# How to give name to the index of an array in embedded document of MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I have a document about employees of a company and each employee has multiple addresses. It is an embedded document

```
    { 
       "_id" : 13,
       "emp_name" : "Joy Pett",
       "emp_gender" : "Male",
       "emp_address" : [
        {
            "street" : "123 Fake Street",
            "city" : "Faketon",
            "state" : "MA"
            },
        {
            "street" : "1 Some Other Street",
            "city" : "Boston",
            "state" : "MA"
        }
]}
```

This is the snapshot of the output when I run the query in RoboMongo

[image]

It inserts the data into the document and the addresses are stored in an embedded array. I want to give a specific name to each address of the employee. for example, Address1, Address2 and so on. By default, Mongodb gives a numeric value to each index of the array, like 0, 1, 2...how can I give a specific name to each index of the address array?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot name indexes to array. In your case you can go by two approach. Both requires changing your database schema. In one way you may define `emp_address` as:

```
"emp_address": 
{
   "address1": 
   {
      "street" : "123 Fake Street",
      "city" : "Faketon",
      "state" : "MA"
   },
   "address2":
   {
      "street" : "1 Some Other Street",
      "city" : "Boston",
      "state" : "MA
   }
}
```

..and so on. In this case you can access elements like `"emp_address.address.street"`.

The other approach is very simple and I would recommend this one to use. In this case you can add one more key inside emp_address array called address_type. A sample is shown below:

```
"emp_address" : [
    {
        "address_type": 1,
        "street" : "123 Fake Street",
        "city" : "Faketon",
        "state" : "MA"
    },
    {
        "address_type": 2
        "street" : "1 Some Other Street",
        "city" : "Boston",
        "state" : "MA"
    }
]
```

To access address1 of employee you can give query like:

> db.employee.find({ "_id": 13, "emp_address.address_type": 1 }, { "emp_address.$": 1})